# Different code output in Jupyter note book and online python IDE

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, tuples

[image: Jupyter output]

On https://www.online-python.com/ , I have got True which I suppose to be the correct the answer since tuples are immutable. Thus can be saved in same memory space. Does anyone have any explanation?

Comment: x = ('apple', 'banana')
y = ('apple', 'banana')

print(x == y)

Comment: The explanation is that the implementation of the REPL is allowed to do it either way. Aside from `None`, the `is` keyword is really only useful for checking for object identity that *the program deliberately arranges* (for example, by doing `y = x`). Please see the linked duplicate for details.

Comment: `print(x is y)`. It worked for Python 3.12.1